React native, pressable issue href being undefined
This is the code I am working with, I am running into an issue of my href being undefined, at runtime upon clicking on any of the links. What am I doing wrong, and why is it happening? I am especially looking for explanations why does it not get picked up, all advice is also welcome.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet, ScrollView, Text, Linking, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { StackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { RootStackParamList } from '../navigation/types';
import pageData from '../../hooks/pageData';
import RenderHTML from 'react-native-render-html';
import { styles } from '../styles';
import htmlTemplate from '../screens/SymptomsScreenContent';

type Props = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'SymptomsScreen'>;

// Define your valid screen names
type ValidScreenNames = keyof RootStackParamList;

const SymptomsScreen = ({ navigation }: Props) => {
  const { pageContent, loading, error } = pageData();
  const [htmlContent, setHtmlContent] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const dynamicHtml = htmlTemplate
      .replace('{{SymptomsScreen.Header}}', pageContent['SymptomsScreen.Header'] || 'Default Header')
      .replace('{{SymptomsScreen.Text}}', pageContent['SymptomsScreen.Text'] || 'Default description.');

    setHtmlContent(dynamicHtml);
  }, [pageContent]);

  const handleLinkPress = (href: string) => {
    //navigation.navigate("CommunicationScreen")
    console.log("HREF IS BEING PROCESSED" + href)
    if (href.startsWith('http://internal.')) {
      const screenName = href.split('.')[1]?.toLowerCase() as ValidScreenNames; // Cast to valid screen names
      if (screenName && navigation.navigate) {
        navigation.navigate(screenName);
      } else {
        console.warn(`Screen ${screenName} does not exist in the navigator.`);
      }
    } else {
      Linking.openURL(href);
    }
  };

  if (loading) return <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />;
  if (error) return <Text style={styles.errorText}>Error: {error}</Text>;

  const renderers = {
    a: (props: { href: string; TDefaultRenderer: React.ComponentType<any> }) => (
      <Pressable onPress={() => handleLinkPress(props.href)}>
        <props.TDefaultRenderer {...props} />
      </Pressable>
    ),
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      <RenderHTML
        contentWidth={300}
        source={{ html: htmlContent }}
        tagsStyles={{ h1: styles.header, p: styles.text }}
        renderers={renderers}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default SymptomsScreen;

// SymptomsScreenContent.js
const htmlTemplate = `
  <html>
    <body>
      <h1>{{SymptomsScreen.Header}}</h1> 
      <ul class=\"font_8\">\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\"><a href=\"http://www.google.com\"><u>ICD-10</u></a> (link)</p></li>\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\">Restless, extroverted</p></li>\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\">Confused, confused</p></li>\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\">Delusions, hallucinated</p></li>\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\">Suspicious, “paranoid”</p></li>\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\">Withdrawn, passive, introverted</p></li>\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\"><a href=\"http://internal.ActionsScreen\"><u>Disturbed circadian rhythm, insomnia</u></a> (Internlink)</p></li>\n  <li><p class=\"font_8\">Inattention, difficulty concentrating</p></li>\n</ul>
    </body>
  </html>
`;

export default htmlTemplate;

I am trying to get the variable href across so I can use in further code, but I simply cannot grasp why am I not picking it up correctly. I have attached html code directly in case of any formatting issues that I am overlooking.
